# Uget shows blank screen

Tags: 16.04, uget

Uget has recently started launching with a blank screen on my Ubuntu 16.04. Only the menu bar and menus are visible. Rest of the window is just black. Downloads start and complete but nothing is visible. Any help would be highly appreciated.

P.S.: I have tried purging it and reinstalling from the ubuntu repositories and also installing itusing the uget.deb file from their official website.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!
All I had to do was go to the view menu and check everything that was unchecked!